# Using OCR on Arabic text

Tags: ocr

A friend has requested I convert an Arabic text .pdf into Word. Google Docs does not seem an option but [new OCR](http://www.newocr.com/) looked promising because Arabic is featured in the 'Recognition language' dropdown. I have failed to get this to work beyond "Error! Text can not be recognized." even with only a few sample pages (111KB).

I'd much appreciate any advice about what I am doing wrong at that site (or even how to access any help available there!) or pointing to other (free!) options that work with Arabic text (preferably that do not require registration and or large downloads). Anyone willing to help please?

Note this .pdf does not have a text layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question was not a request for recommendation of the best program (presumably that would be off topic here) but about either getting new OCR to work the way it seemed it was supposed to, or for any other free converter that works for Arabic text I think it is fair to say that [OCR Convert](http://www.ocrconvert.com) is an answer. This is online, free and requires no registration.

It did not manage all 67 pages at one time (after about 15 minutes the program reported an error) but it has converted 10 pages at one time. The quality/accuracy is suspect (based on translation with Google) but I am happy to consider that a separate issue.